# How to draw part of a circle without using PIE mode?

Tags: p5.js

[image: Triangle sections of circle]

I need help drawing part of a circle please

The top and bottom pieces above can be drawn simply using `arc();`

But how do you draw the other two parts of the circle? The triangular bits?

The only way I can think of is to use PIE mode; something like this.

This way makes it really hard to generate using loops, etc.

It feels like there must be a simpler way.

I am using P5.js

```
  function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  //Draw BG
  background(200,240,240);
  stroke(0);


  fill("blue");
  arc(140, 175, 180, 180, radians(345), radians(15), PIE);

  fill("yellow");
  arc(185, 180, 90, 90, radians(30), radians(180), CHORD);

  fill("red");
  arc(185, 170, 90, 90, radians(180), radians(330), CHORD);

  noLoop();
}
```

[image: Output of my code]

Comment: Because I’m using P5.js

Comment: I guess the most exact approach would be using 'bezierVertex', but this involves quite some calculations. 
You may already know that your arc example doesn't add up to a proper circle.

Comment: I created a segmentedCircle class for Processing a while back. Basically you can draw circles with a different number of anchor points. 

https://pastebin.com/63AM1cYt

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of janky, but you could start with a single circle and just occlude sections of it with shapes that are the same color as the background

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(200);
  
  translate(width/2, height/2)
  fill(255)
  
  circle(0, 0, 100)
  noStroke();
  fill(200)
  
  let x0 = -50
  let y0 = 0
  
  triangle(x0, y0, 100, 100, 100, 110)
  triangle(x0, y0, 100, 0, 100, 10)
  triangle(x0, y0, 100, -100, 120, -140)
}
```